# User login info is deleted when I delete posts

Tags: python, django

User login info is deleted when I delete posts.I wrote in views.py

```
def top(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if loginform.is_valid():
            user = loginform.get_user()
            info = Info.objects.order_by('-created_at')
            return render(request, 'top.html', {'info':info,'user': user})

    loginform = LoginForm()
    info = Info.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'info':info,'loginform':loginform,'user': request.user})

def delete(request):
    delete_ids = request.POST.getlist('delete_ids')
    if delete_ids:
        Info.objects.filter(id__in=delete_ids).delete()

    return redirect(reverse("app:top"))
```

in top.html

```
      <div>
                        {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
                                <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
                        {% else %}
                                    <form action="" method="POST">
                                        <div>
                                            {{ loginform.non_field_errors }}

                                            {% for field in loginform %}
                                                {{ field }}
                                                {{ field.errors }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>

                                        <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                    </form>
                        {% endif %}

      <div>

                <form  action="{% url 'app:delete' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for i in info %}
                        <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete_ids" value="{{ i.pk }}" />
                        <div>
                            <p>{{ i.name }}</p>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}

                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
```

Firstly I login to this app by putting LOGIN button,user.username is shown. And when I put Delete button to delete info,login info is deleted too(user.username is not shown).info is deleted but I really cannot understand why login info is deleted too.I cannot send user's info in `redirect(reverse("app:top"))`,so shouldn't I use redirect?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to login user. Try to add [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) method:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def top(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if loginform.is_valid():
            user = loginform.get_user()
            login(request, user)
```

Also it's better to use `is_authenticated` instead of `is_anonymous`:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```